# How to pass IEnumerable<SelectListItem> collection to a MVC Partial View with only one database lookup per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlistitem, dropdownlistfor

Suppose that given a partial view for an html table, there exists a nested partial view for each table row such as the following:

Outer Partial View

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PurchaseItems.Count; i++)
{ 
  @Html.Partial("_PurchaseItemsDetail", Model.PurchaseItems[i])
}     
</tbody>
</table>
```

Inner Partial View, NOTE: this partial view may used multiple times by the outer view in a single request, however it may also be used just once if requested using AJAX

```
<tr id="@Model.ID">
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemName)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Cost)</td>
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, CATEGORY_COLLECTION)
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Problem**: given this inner view that is intended to be flexible, what is the best way to query the database and temporarily store the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` collection to be used with the dropdown?  Ways that I can think of:

Method 1: this seems to be the easiest, however it feels like it violates MVC principles.  Evaluate in the inner partial view and store in `ViewData` collection in such a way that the database is only hit once:

```
    @{
     if (ViewData["Categories"] == null)
     {
       ViewData["Categories"] = API.GetCategories();
     }
    }
```

then later in the view

```
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, ViewData["Categories"])
  </td>
```

This is nice because the view takes care of itself as far as determining how to populate its containing dropdown. It does not rely on the view model.

Method 2: same as above, except set the `ViewData` in the various controller methods that return the inner partial view.  This way seems to be more in line with MVC best practices, however it seems more tedious and confusing to maintain given that each controller method needs to set the `ViewData` properly, as well as create the necessary view model.

Method 3: this seems the most work, the hardest to maintain, but most in accordance with MVC principles. Avoid using the `ViewData` entirely, but store a reference to the collection along with the other properties in the partial view model. It would be the responsibility of the controller to create the collection, and then store a reference in each of the table rows' view models.

```
public class PurchaseItemModel
{
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public decimal Cost { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
  
  // add this
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and in each controller that server the inner view

```
// if dealing with multiple rows (GET)
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> collection = API.GetPurchaseItemList();

foreach (PurchaseItemModel pim in OuterModel.PurchaseItemModels)
{
  pim.Categories = collection;
}
```

or

```
// if dealing with a single row (Ajax)
purchaseItem.Categories = API.GetPurchaseItemList();
```

then later in the view

```
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, x.Categories)
  </td>
```

Perhaps this is just subjective question, but it seems like there would be a best practice for this type of situation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This isn't a very good question - instead of describing vague, abstract scenarios, describe your *specific* problem *with supporting code*.

Comment: @AntP, I have edited my question.  Perhaps you will find that the identified shortcomings have been fixed.

Comment: Good job, the question is much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and create a ViewModel Class such as

```
public class PurchaseItemViewModel
{
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public decimal Cost { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public IEnumberable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

  public PurchaseItemViewModel(PurchaseItemModel item, List<Category> categories)
  {
       //initialize item and categories
  }
}
```

In the controller get all the items then get all the categories then set the Purchase items to the ViewModel and set the categories. So you will pass the ViewModel Class to the view.

Comment: I definitely agree that your answer follows the proper MVC design pattern.  However this must be programmed for every controller action that will serve this view, yet the logic for obtaining these select items is always the same.  Is there a specific reason why you would avoid using the ViewData?

Comment: Of course, you can use viewdata if that is your preference. However, it is recommended to use viewdata for objects that are unrelated to the model or viewmodel.

Answer (score 2):

Method 3 is the way to go - but don't make it so complicated.  Have two properties - a `PurchaseItem` property and a `Categories` property.  Then instantiate per iteration and set the properties.

Loose example:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PurchaseItems.Count; i++)
{ 
    var vm = new PurchaseItemsDetailViewModel()
        {
            PurchaseItem = Model.PurchaseItems[i],
            Categories = Model.CategoriesSelectList // or whatever holds the categories select list
        };
  @Html.Partial("_PurchaseItemsDetail", vm)
}     
</tbody>
</table>


<tr id="@Model.PurchaseItem.ID">
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PurchaseItem.ItemName)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PurchaseItem.Cost)</td>
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PurchaseItem.Category, x.Categories)
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I like your use of the object initializer.  I still keep getting surprised at how easy it can make things.

Comment: What is the point of a View Model if it is created by the View?